# .htaccess append .abc.local to URL's

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Im trying to get my htaccess to append .abc.local to my internal site with the user doesn't. So lets say the go to `http://kb` I want the URL to be redirected or some other method to be `http://kb.abc.local`. Is this possible or should I look in another direction?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^kb$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://kb.abc.local$1 [R=301, L]
```

That should do it.

Comment: When you enter the URL `http://kb`, do you get redirected to `http://kb.abc.local` and then get the Internal Server Error or do you get the error without being redirected? Is your VirtualHost set up with both kb and kb.abc.local as ServerName or ServerAlias?

Answer (score 0):

This sort of domain name mutation is handled by the local DNS resolver, via its "domain search suffix" option. This is handled by the client OS, and its behavior cannot be modified by the server.